# Background image not displayed when the height is auto

Tags: html, css

If I give some value to the height the background image is displayed, but it doesn't show when set to auto. I don't know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pageloading</title>
    <style>
     #topheader{
         background-image:url("header.png");
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-size: cover;
         width:100%;
         height: auto; /* it works if i give some px */
                }
        </style>

</head>
<body>
     <div id="topheader">

     </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that because 'div' will fit his size to its content,

in your case the div is empty and thats why he didn't show the background image,

unless you give him Measurement size in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

`height: auto` gives the div a height of 0 because there is no content in it and it **auto**matically adjusts the height.